# Trigger and reverse CSS transition with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I am currently exploring the possibilities of the [FLIP technique](https://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/) which reduces all CSS transitions only to `transform` and `opacity` (because of GPU-acceleration). It involves manipulating styles directly with Javascript. Although it is not very hard to trigger such a transition, I've found myself unable to reverse it. Normally a transition defined within CSS on e.g. hover is reversed automatically when you stop hovering. But CSS is not enough to trigger (and reverse) transition on clicks. I want to be able to do the following:

a) Click on an item (and trigger size change by e.g. CSS class toggling)
b) Calculate the difference between its initial and new size and trigger a `transform` with `transition`
c) Click on it again *while it is changing its size*
d) Reverse the transition from the position it was in when clicked on

My problem is with the d) step. For some reason the element abruptly changes its size to neither the old nor the new size but to a completely different size. I have an example of what I'm trying to do here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-snowflake-47t59

Click on a square and then click on it again while it's enlarging.

Is there any reliable way to properly do what I'm trying to do? Are there good alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a working solution (it imports `rematrix` library to make calculations with transformation matrices easier). Both this solution and the simpler one by Richard are capable of 60fps animation - I guess the difference is the amount of cases each approach can deal with.

https://codesandbox.io/s/working-transform-reverse-urc16

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for. Also, it seems to me that you don't quite understand `requestAnimationFrame` fully. It's made to replace a technique that involves recursive calls of `setInterval` to change the CSS property of an element every few milliseconds (read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/)). So I suggest reading more about `requestAnimationFrame` first.

I'd like to note that this animation below can be far more easily made simply using CSS transition. Furthermore, MDN mentions that both have more or less similar performance anyway (read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance)). Still, here's a minimal working example of what you want:

```js
let clicked = false;
let square = document.querySelector(".small-sq");
let expandID
let retractID

square.style.transformOrigin = 'top left'
square.style.transform = 'scale(1)'
square.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let timeStart = new Date()
  let currentScale = parseFloat(square.style.transform.slice(6, -1))
  if (!clicked) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(retractID)
    expandID = requestAnimationFrame(() => repeat(timeStart, currentScale, clicked))
  }
  else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(expandID)
    retractID = requestAnimationFrame(() => repeat(timeStart, currentScale, clicked))
  }
  clicked = !clicked
})

function repeat(timeStart, currentScale, status) {
    let timeDifference = new Date() - timeStart
    if (status) {
      let scaleValue = currentScale + (1 * timeDifference / 5000) > 2 ? 2 : currentScale + (1 * timeDifference / 5000)
      square.style.transform = `scale(${scaleValue})`
      expandID = requestAnimationFrame(() => repeat(timeStart, scaleValue, status))
      if (scaleValue >= 2)
        cancelAnimationFrame(expandID)
    }
    else {
      let scaleValue = currentScale - (1 * timeDifference / 5000) < 1 ? 1 : currentScale - (1 * timeDifference / 5000)
      square.style.transform = `scale(${scaleValue})`
      retractID = requestAnimationFrame(() => repeat(timeStart, scaleValue, status))
      if (scaleValue <= 1)
        cancelAnimationFrame(retractID)
    }
    
  }
```

```css
.small-sq {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(131, 42, 131);
}
.big-sq {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(131, 42, 131);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="small-sq"></div>
</div>
```

If you use CSS transition, then it can be converted to the following:

```js
let square = document.querySelector('.small-sq')

square.addEventListener('click', e => {
  square.classList.toggle('toggled')
})
```

```css
.small-sq {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(131, 42, 131);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
.small-sq.toggled {
  transform: scale(2)
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="small-sq"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. I am aware about performance and I think your second example can be used in a lot of cases. But there are some cases where it is not enough (animating DOM position change, e.g. list shuffling, or shared element transitions).